# 2 tables join, with ids IN list(), limit the number of models for each element in list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 models A, B. B has a ForeignKey to A

A

```
id | name | sec_id    
1    char     5    
2    char     5       
3    char     7 
4    char     5 
5    char     6 
6    char     6 
7    char     6
```

B

```
id | name      | a_id other   
1    char1-1      1    -     
2    char1-2      1    -    
3    char2-1      2    -
4    char2-2      2    -
5    char3-1      3    -
```

**I want to:**

- get A elements up to 2 per each sec_id from a list of sec_id - >

-> For example if `sec_id_list=(5,7)`, I will get A corresponding to id 1,2 for sec_id 5 and 3 for sec_id 7, nothing for sec_id 6)

- for each A element get the first corresponding B element

  id  name_A sec_id  name_B

  ```
  1  char     5      char1-1
  2  char     5      char1-2 
  3  char     7      char1-3
  ```

I start with:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, A.sec_id, B.name FROM A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, name, FROM B) ON B.sec_id=A.id WHERE  P.sec_id IN (5,7)
```

I tried to use count or Distinct ON, but I failed, to limit the number to two for each sec_id in the IN list

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - see I want to: section. Is more clear now ? if not, what is not clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting from `A` or `B` directly, replace them with a subquery selecting the rows with the lowest two or one IDs per `sec_id` or `a_id`. That can be done by checking whether the count of rows with lower or equal IDs is less than or equal to the respective limit. Left join the `A` substitute with the `B` substitute and put the list of wanted `sec_id` in the `WHERE`, as you've done already.

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.sec_id,
       b.name
       FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM A ai
                    WHERE (SELECT ai.id,
                                  ai.name,
                                  ai.sec_id
                                  FROM A aii
                                  WHERE aii.sec_id = aii.sec_id
                                        AND aii.id <= ai.id) <= 2) a
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT bi.a_id,
                              bi.name
                              FROM B bi
                              WHERE (SELECT count(*)
                                            FROM B bii
                                            WHERE bii.a_id = bi.a_id
                                                  AND bii.id <= bi.id) <= 1) b
                      ON b.a_id = a.id
       WHERE a.sec_id IN (5,
                          7);
```

(Untested, as no DDL or DML was provided.)